# Align icn in right corner without throwing off other items

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the edit icon in the top rig of the div without effecting the contents of the div. I have tried a few things such as `float:right` but i cannot figure out how to do it without a effecting the div contents. You can see even if its on the left it is still moving the contents [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rxp9Ld2n/34/)

```css
.profile {
    border-color: #EDEDED;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    
}

.profile-section-img {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.profile-img {
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.edit-profile-icn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    
    
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d457e3e281.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="profile">
            <a class="edit-profile-icn" href=""><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i></a>

            <div class="profile-section-img">
                <img class="rounded-circle profile-img profile-section-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png" />
                <h2 class="account-heading">My Username</h2>

                <p class="text-secondary">Hello world!</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Set `.profile` to relative, and set `.edit-profile-icn` to `right: 0`

Answer (score 0):

If you make it position absolute it won't affect the positioning of any other element.

You can get to the right by positioning it right: 0 (relative to its parent, so we give the parent a position as well).

```html
<style>
  .profile {
    border-color: #EDEDED;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    max-width: 500px;
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .profile a:first-child {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }
  
  .profile-section-img {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
  
  .profile-img {
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
  }
  
  .edit-profile-icn {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d457e3e281.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>A Basic HTML5 Template</title>


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css?v=1.0">

</head>

<body>



  <div class="profile">


    <a class="edit-profile-icn" href=""><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg"></i></a>



    <div class="profile-section-img">
      <img class="rounded-circle profile-img profile-section-img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280.png">
      <h2 class="account-heading">My Username</h2>


      <p class="text-secondary">Hello world!</p>


    </div>
  </div>


  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Incidentally, I noticed that you have a slightly off center 'central' bit - it has a right margin set - I assume that is intentional and not to do with how you want the icon displayed?